# AddThis plugin showing cross domain error

Tags: wordpress, addthis

I'm using addthis wordpress plugin for the social connectivity in a website. Strange but it is showing the error in the following image,

[image]

I googled about this type of error they are saying like the link in the iframe is different with the site link, you cannot share data between different urls like that.

But I haven't done anything like that, I just enabled the plugin and configured the social buttons in the addthis site.

I'm using wordpress 4 and the plugin is addthis for wordpress latest version.

Can someone please tell me how to sort out this issue.

Comment: Do you have reCaptcha plugin installed?